# Access Query: Running total without using DSum (or another approach all together)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using DSum is taking an astronomical amount of time to calculate my needed numbers. It seems to take roughly 0.1 seconds per row on my query, which has 4300 rows. This means that every time I refresh my DB, it takes about 8 minutes...

I'm neck deep in queries here, but if you follow along, it should be fully coherent. That said, if you know how to get from A to B with the two tables and my desired output, please feel free to help me out. I have a working method below, but like I said it just takes way too long.

I start with the two below tables. What I want to do is subtract my on-hand QTY from my required QTY, and roll forward any continued excess to the next date. However, I do not want to roll-forward my required QTY.

**On Hand**

```
Product  |  QTY
   A     |  125
```

**Required** (in this example, I need 50 per month)

```
Product  |  QTY Req  |  Date Req
   A     |     50    |   1-1-18
   A     |     50    |   2-1-18
   A     |     50    |   3-1-18
   A     |     50    |   4-1-18
   A     |     50    |   5-1-18
   A     |     50    |   6-1-18
```

**And, this is my desired output:** (in this example, I exhaust my on hand QTY over 3 months, and still need up to 50 a month after that.

```
Product  |  Build QTY |  Date Req
   A     |      0     |   1-1-18
   A     |      0     |   2-1-18
   A     |      25    |   3-1-18
   A     |      50    |   4-1-18
   A     |      50    |   5-1-18
   A     |      50    |   6-1-18
```

---

---

## Step 1:

Assign a false date to my on-hand QTY (manually set to be before any required dates). This is so we can make a union query to consolidate all supply/demand QTYs.

**On Hand Summary** (new query)

```
SELECT
  DateValue("12/1/2017") AS [Date],
  [On Hand].[Product],
  [On Hand].[QTY];
```

## Step 2:

Make a Union Query so we can get all date↔product combos.

**uQuery** (new query)

```
SELECT 
  [On Hand Summary].[Date] AS [Date],
  [On Hand Summary].[Product] AS [Product]
  FROM [On Hand Summary]
UNION SELECT 
  [Required].[Date Req] AS [Date],
  [Required].[Product] AS [Product]
  FROM [Required];
```

## Step 3:

Consolidate QTY by product & date. Here I multiply on-hand QTY by -1 so that we can prep the amount to be rolled-forward.

I also wrap my QTYs in `Iif(IsNull())` so that I can replace null values with 0.

**Data Consolidation 1** (new query)

```
SELECT
  [uQuery].Date,
  [uQuery].Product,
  IIf(IsNull(-1*[On Hand Summary]![QTY]),0,-1*[OH Summary]![QTY]) AS [OH QTY],
  IIf(IsNull([Required]![QTY Req]),0,[Required]![QTY Req]) AS [Req QTY],
  [OH QTY]+[Req QTY] AS [Combined QTY]
FROM ([uQuery] 
  LEFT JOIN [On Hand Summary] ON 
    ([uQuery].Product = [On Hand Summary].Product) AND 
    ([uQuery].Date = [On Hand Summary].Date)) 
  LEFT JOIN Forecast ON 
    ([uQuery].Product = Required.Product) AND 
    ([uQuery].Date = Required.[Date Req]);
```

## Step 4 (adding DSum, which takes too long):

On this query, I pull in `Product`, `Date`, and `Combined QTY` from the first Data Consolidation query, and add a `Roll QTY` column.

**Data Consolidation 2** (new query)

```
Product  |   Date  |  Combined QTY  |  Roll QTY  
   A     | 12-1-17 |      -125      |    -125    
   A     |  1-1-18 |       50       |    -75     
   A     |  2-1-18 |       50       |    -25     
   A     |  3-1-18 |       50       |     25     
   A     |  4-1-18 |       50       |     75     
   A     |  5-1-18 |       50       |     125    
   A     |  6-1-18 |       50       |     175
```

For the `Roll QTY`, I use this expression:

> Roll QTY: DSum("[QTY]","Data Consolidation 2","[Data Consolidation 1]![Product] = '" & [Product] & "' And [Data Consolidation 1]![Date] <= #" & [Date] & "#")

Now, this gives me what I need, but like I said it takes roughly 0.1 seconds per row. Across 4300 rows (only to get bigger), that's an unacceptable amount of time for calculations.

## Step 5 (unimplemented)

I don't need help with this part; I know what I need to do. But I just wanted to include this if you want to know how I will get to my desired output.

I plan on creating one last query that calculated the following

> Minimum([Combined QTY], Maximum([Roll QTY],0))

These are traditional `max` and `min` functions, which I understand [I'll need to implement a VB module](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/209857/acc2000-how-to-find-minimum-or-maximum-value-across-fields-of-record).

---

---

## EDIT:

I reformatted some of my DB, but I think I made it simpler. I managed to make just one input table, where "on hand" quantity is represented as a negative value.

```
Product  |  QTY Req  |  Date Req
   A     |    -125   |   12-1-18
   A     |     50    |   1-1-18
   A     |     50    |   2-1-18
   A     |     50    |   3-1-18
   A     |     50    |   4-1-18
   A     |     50    |   5-1-18
   A     |     50    |   6-1-18
```

Is there a way to roll this forward without using DSUM?

To confirm, the final value should not be less than 0, but not more than the monthly amount.

Comment: Not that good with access, but just wanted to comment that this is a great question.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to explain your question, but still want to ask for clarification. Can you open with what you want to do in laymans terms, before jumping to SQL, and provide short example results of step 1 and 2? I have a feeling we can achieve your desired result on one or two steps

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Added some extra info at the top. Does that help?

Comment: If I can reword it, you want to calculate a running sum of your required quantity, subtract your required quantity from it, and then have 3 scenario's: if the running sum minus your product on hand is less than 0, you return 0. If the running sum minus your product on hand is greater than 0, but less than the required quantity, you return the required quantity minus the remainder of that equation. If the running sum minus your product on hand is greater than the required quantity, you return the required quantity. Is that correct?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes, exactly!

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth And just to clarify, my method works completely. The only issue I'm having is the amount of time it takes for `DSum()` to work its magic.

Comment: Well, allow me to totally go a different way, and you will probably end up with something way faster and more simple :)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth You're the best!

Answer (score 2):

The following query calculates the running sum in a subquery, then joins in the quantity on hand in the outer query, and does the comparisons and returns the results as explained in my comment.

```
SELECT 
    rs.Product,
    SWITCH( 
        RunningSum - h.[QTY] < 0, 0, 
        RunningSum - h.[QTY] < rs.[QTY Req], rs.[QTY Req] - (RunningSum - h.[QTY]), 
        TRUE, rs.[QTY Req]
    ) AS [Build QTY],
    rs.[Date Req], RunningSum
FROM
  (SELECT
     (
        SELECT Sum(r.[QTY Req])
        FROM [Required] r
        WHERE r.[Date Req] <= o.[Date Req]
        AND r.[Product] = o.[Product]
        AND r.[QTY req] > 0
    ) AS RunningSum,
    o.Product,
    o.[QTY Req],
    o.[Date Req]
   FROM [Required] o
   WHERE o.[QTY req] > 0) rs
LEFT JOIN (SELECT oh.[QTY req]*-1 As QTY, Product FROM [Required] oh WHERE oh.[QTY req] < 0) h ON h.[Product] = rs.[Product]
```

---

**Explanation:**

The subquery that calculates the running sum is the following query:

```
SELECT Sum([QTY Req])
FROM [Required] r
WHERE r.[Date Req] <= o.[Date Req]
AND r.[Product] = o.[Product]
AND r.[QTY req] > 0
```

`r` and `o` are aliases in this query. `r` is the most inner instance of the `required` table. `r` is the outer instance of that table. For each row in the outer instance, I'm calculating the sum for all previous days where the product code is the same.

You could use a `DSum` instead of `SELECT Sum([QTY Req]) FROM [Required] r WHERE r.[Date Req] < o.[Date Req] AND r.[Product] = o.[Product]`, but that has a negative impact on performance.

Then, in the outer query, this subquery is referred to as `rs`, and I join in `On Hand` as `h` (On **H**and, I already used `o`) and use the logic I've explained in the comment.

Comment: I have to step aside for a while, but in the meantime; can you explain the shorthand? `rs`, `h`, `o`? Once I have it up, I'll let you know how it works when I get back.

Comment: See my current edit for an explanation (and a working version)

Comment: Admittedly, the table/query names I gave were placeholders, since I have confidential data in the titles/headers. That said, I got it to compile after replacing the names. However, the numbers seem off, and I'm not sure what the next step to troubleshoot is.

Comment: That's odd. I validated this query with your sample data. Can you provide sample data where the result of this query is wrong, and explain how it's wrong? (Will look at it later, busy now)

Comment: Note that I've made a minor edit to possibly reflect better what you want

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but I had to do some reformatting of my tables and queries. I was wondering if you could rewrite based on the change? I think it should be simpler. I've edited my post above with my example.

Comment: Nope, you've broken database normalisation, and made it more complex. Don't store two different kinds of information in a single table. Also, afaik it should work, but you said it didn't. I can't fix it if you can't provide sample data where it doesn't work (because for me it does)

Comment: Hmm, ok. I need it combined for other queries (since it's technically the same kind of data from a "QTY Required" perspective; negative means I don't need it, positive means I do), so I may just have to convert this to a Make Table query, and stomach a 5+ minute processing time everytime I need it re-synced.

Comment: Well, I _can_ get it to work with the new format like it previously did, but I still don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: Sorry, nothing was wrong with the SQL you wrote for the previous iteration. I unfortunately had to make some fundamental changes to my database to accommodate other reports, which made my initial input formats obsolete.

Comment: See the current edit. The complexity increased substantially, since now I need to use an extra subquery, extra criteria, and a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. All these things could have a substantial impact on performance too.