# How to create a SQL item history stockcard in the MS ACCESS database in VB.NET

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner-join, union

I'm trying to create a SQL item history stockcard using an MS Access database in VB.NET. I have the SQL below, but it's not right yet:

```
SELECT CodeProduct, Sum(IIf(Cat="IN", Qty, 0)) AS [IN], Sum(IIf(Cat="Out", Qty, 0)) AS OUT, Sum(Qty * IIf(Cat="OUT", -1, 1)) AS BALANCE
FROM (
    SELECT [No], Invono, CodeProduct,Qty, "IN" AS Cat FROM PurchaseDetail
    UNION 
    SELECT [No], Invono, CodeProduct, Qty, "OUT" FROM SalesDetail
)  AS DetailUNION
WHERE CodeProduct = 'A'
GROUP BY CodeProduct;
```

Results from the above SQL code

| CodeProduct | IN | OUT | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 75 | 65 | 10 |

Sample Data :

Table `Purchase`

| Invono | Invodate | Transaction | Remark | NameSC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 18-Oct-23 | Purchase | REPEAT AGAIN | TEST1 |
| 1001 | 19-Oct-23 | Purchase |  | TEST2 |

Table `PurchaseDetail`

| Invono | No | Codeproduct | Qty | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | A | 50 | WHITE |
| 1000 | 2 | B | 35 |  |
| 1001 | 1 | C | 17 |  |
| 1001 | 2 | A | 25 | BROWN |

Table `Sales`

| Invono | Invodate | Transaction | Remark | NameSC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 18-Oct-23 | Sales |  | TEST10 |
| 1001 | 19-Oct-23 | Sales |  | TEST20 |
| 1002 | 20-Oct-23 | Sales |  | TEST30 |

Table `SalesDetail`

| Invono | No | Codeproduct | Qty | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | A | 25 | WHITE |
| 1001 | 1 | C | 35 |  |
| 1001 | 2 | A | 15 | WHITE |
| 1002 | 1 | A | 25 | BROWN |

Desired Result

| Invono | Invodate | Transaction | No | Codeproduct | Info | Remark | NameSC | IN | OUT | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 18-Oct-23 | Purchase | 1 | A | WHITE | REPEAT AGAIN | TEST1 | 50 |  | 50 |
| 1000 | 18-Oct-23 | Sales | 1 | A | WHITE |  | TEST10 |  | 25 | 25 |
| 1001 | 19-Oct-23 | Purchase | 2 | A | BROWN |  | TEST2 | 25 |  | 50 |
| 1001 | 19-Oct-23 | Sales | 2 | A | WHITE |  | TEST20 |  | 15 | 35 |
| 1002 | 20-Oct-23 | Sales | 1 | A | BROWN |  | TEST30 |  | 25 | 10 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: It's not clear yet if you want a row per date/transaction or a row per date/transaction/InvoNo, nor is it clear how you will decide which value among the several possible to show for NamesSC.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , `It's not clear yet if you want a row per date/transaction or a row per date/transaction/InvoNo` I want  a row per date/transaction/InvoNo/Codeproduct .`how you will decide which value among the several possible to show for NamesSC` NamesSC is the name of the supplier and customer

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn ,  `NamesSC` is the name of the supplier and customer. NamesSC from table `Purchase` and `Sales` Based on `Invono`. any suggestions from you for the NameSC

Comment: It seems the sample data for the Sales table is incorrect.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh , you are right I have fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include Sales and Purchase tables in the UNION lines with INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT InvoDate, Transaction, InvoNo, CodeProduct, NameSC, 
Sum(IIf(Transaction="Purchase", Qty, 0)) AS [IN], 
Sum(IIf(Transaction="Sales", Qty, 0)) AS OUT, 
Sum(Qty * IIf(Transaction="Sales", -1, 1)) AS BALANCE
FROM (
    SELECT [No], InvoDate, Purchase.Invono, CodeProduct, Qty, NameSC, Transaction 
    FROM PurchaseDetail INNER JOIN Purchase 
    ON Purchase.Invono = PurchaseDetail.Invono
    UNION 
    SELECT [No], InvoDate, Sales.Invono, CodeProduct, Qty, NameSC, Transaction 
    FROM SalesDetail INNER JOIN Sales 
    ON Sales.Invono = SalesDetail.Invono
)  AS DetailUNION
WHERE CodeProduct = 'A'
GROUP BY InvoDate, Transaction, InvoNo, CodeProduct, NameSC;
```

| InvoDate | Transaction | InvoNo | CodeProduct | NameSC | IN | OUT | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/18/2023 | Purchase | 1000 | A | TEST1 | 50 | 0 | 50 |
| 10/18/2023 | Sales | 1000 | A | TEST10 | 0 | 25 | -25 |
| 10/19/2023 | Purchase | 1001 | A | TEST2 | 25 | 0 | 25 |
| 10/19/2023 | Sales | 1001 | A | TEST20 | 0 | 15 | -15 |
| 10/20/2023 | Sales | 1002 | A | TEST30 | 0 | 25 | -25 |

The BALANCE shown in your output sample is a running total. Running total in query is a common topic. It is difficult to accomplish in Access query. One approach uses DSum(), another requires correlated subquery. Each can perform slowly with large dataset. It is simple to produce a running total in Access report using Sorting & Grouping and textbox RunningSum property.

Your running balance is by CodeProduct. Following version shows running total. Unfortunately, value on each row will not agree with IN OUT BALANCE values because running total subquery is not calculating records in the same order. Also, when there are multiple records for the same date, they show the same value because there is no way to differentiate them in the subquery for sequential calc. This is usually accomplished by querying a table directly and including a unique ID field such as autonumber field in the WHERE clause. Since your data set is a complex query, not just a table, this is not available. However, final balance on last row is correct. Excluded WHERE clause so results will show for all CodeProduct values. Add filtering as you see fit.

First, the DetailUNION SQL must be a saved query object that is then called to perform the aggregation and running total. Embedding its SQL as a subquery fails.

New Info: Including NameSC criteria in RunningBal subquery does allow differentiation of multiple same-date records and calculations will then agree. However, I doubt actual data in table can be relied on.

```
SELECT InvoDate, Transaction, InvoNo, CodeProduct, NameSC, 
Sum(IIf(Transaction="Purchase",Qty,0)) AS [IN], 
Sum(IIf(Transaction="Sales",Qty,0)) AS OUT, 
Sum(Qty*IIf(Transaction="Sales",-1,1)) AS BALANCE,
(SELECT Sum(Qty * IIf(Transaction="Sales",-1,1)) 
 FROM DetailUNION as Dupe 
 WHERE Dupe.CodeProduct=DetailUNION.CodeProduct 
 AND Dupe.InvoDate<=DetailUNION.InvoDate 
 AND Dupe.NameSC<=DetailUNION.NameSC) AS RunningBal
FROM DetailUNION
GROUP BY InvoDate, Transaction, InvoNo, CodeProduct, NameSC
ORDER BY CodeProduct, InvoDate, NameSC;
```

| InvoDate | Transaction | InvoNo | CodeProduct | NameSC | IN | OUT | BALANCE | RunningBal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/18/2023 | Purchase | 1000 | A | TEST1 | 50 | 0 | 50 | 50 |
| 10/18/2023 | Sales | 1000 | A | TEST10 | 0 | 25 | -25 | 25 |
| 10/19/2023 | Purchase | 1001 | A | TEST2 | 25 | 0 | 25 | 50 |
| 10/19/2023 | Sales | 1001 | A | TEST20 | 0 | 15 | -15 | 35 |
| 10/20/2023 | Sales | 1002 | A | TEST30 | 0 | 25 | -25 | 10 |
| 10/18/2023 | Purchase | 1000 | B | TEST1 | 35 | 0 | 35 | 35 |
| 10/19/2023 | Purchase | 1001 | C | TEST2 | 17 | 0 | 17 | 17 |
| 10/19/2023 | Sales | 1001 | C | TEST20 | 0 | 35 | -35 | -18 |

Comment: thank you for your answer.  For `BALANCE` so I want the value to remain positive if the number of sales is greater then the value becomes negative

Comment: Can use ABS() function: `Abs(Sum(Qty * IIf(Transaction="Sales", -1, 1))) AS BALANCE`, although that seems to be misleading. Your output example does not reflect the raw data samples.

Comment: `Your output example does not reflect the raw data samples.` 
in the previous sample data there was something wrong in Table `Sales` for `Invono` so so the `OUT` value must be different from the `Desired Result`. Your code `Sum(IIf(Transaction="Sales", Qty, 0)) AS [IN] ` should be `Sum(IIf(Transaction="Sales", Qty, 0)) AS OUT ` and `Sum(IIf(Transaction="Purchase", Qty, 0)) AS OUT` should be `Sum(IIf(Transaction="Purchase", Qty, 0)) AS [IN]`

Comment: `Can use ABS() function: Abs(Sum(Qty * IIf(Transaction="Sales", -1, 1))) AS BALANCE` If I use the function, the problem  If the total Qty from the sales table is more then so the result in the balance remains positive, the result should be negative

Comment: Sorry, got Sales and Purchase backwards in IN and OUT expressions (fixed). Doesn't change results of BALANCE calc. And I misread your first comment. So don't use Abs().

Comment: I just realized your BALANCE is showing a running total. This would be much more complicated in Access query. One approach uses DSum(). Otherwise, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997802/access-query-running-total-without-using-dsum-or-another-approach-all-together. It is simple to calculate running in Access report using RunningSum property of textbox.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `This would be much more complicated in Access query. One approach uses DSum(). Otherwise, review stackoverflow.com/questions/47997802/…. It is simple to calculate running in Access report using RunningSum property of textbox.` `DSum()` This means it can't be used in SQL and also this is a problem if I run it in VB.net

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255696/discussion-between-june7-and-siwa86).

Comment: Implementing flattening and running sum in pure ms-access query is complicated and tedious. If this is just a database for a winform/webform application, then it is much easier to accomplish in vb.net (as mentioned in title). I think adding a vb.net tag is necessary.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh ,Thank you for your reply. Yes, you are right, this is for just a database view  for a winformand . you mean the calculations for these columns using datatable or also via datagridview columns

Comment: You can simply achieve this using LINQ on datatable(s) (or list of class(es)) and then set the result as the datasource of a datagridview. But, working directly on datagridview is not a good idea.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh , 
Thank you for your response and your idea is good. If possible, I will make a new post, maybe you can help me

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh , [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345606/how-to-make-balance-column-calculations-from-stockcards-with-dapper-in-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment136355175_77345606) here is my new post link maybe you can help me

Comment: @June7 , 
thank you for your perfect answer