# How to make balance column calculations from stockcards with dapper in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, datagridview

I'm trying to balance column calculations from stockcards with dapper in VB.NET. I have the code below, but it's not right yet:

Please Guide me.

Thanks

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim scs As New Stockcardservice()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = scs.LoadData("A")
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Stockcardservice
    Private Function CreateConnection() As String
        Return ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Stockcard2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    End Function
    Public Function LoadData(ByVal code As String) As IEnumerable(Of DTOStockcard)
        Dim sql = $"SELECT DetailUNION.InvoNo,DetailUNION.InvoDate, DetailUNION.Transaction,DetailUNION.[No], DetailUNION.CodeProduct, DetailUNION.Info, DetailUNION.Remark, DetailUNION.NameSC, Sum(IIf(Transaction='Purchase',Qty,0)) AS [IN], Sum(IIf(Transaction='Sales',Qty,0)) AS OUT
FROM (SELECT [No], InvoDate, Purchase.Invono,CodeProduct, Qty, Info,Remark,NameSC,Transaction 
    FROM PurchaseDetail INNER JOIN Purchase 
    ON Purchase.Invono = PurchaseDetail.Invono
    UNION 
    SELECT [No], InvoDate, Sales.Invono,CodeProduct, Qty,Info,Remark,NameSC,Transaction 
    FROM SalesDetail INNER JOIN Sales 
    ON Sales.Invono = SalesDetail.Invono
)  AS DetailUNION
WHERE (((DetailUNION.CodeProduct)='{code}'))
GROUP BY DetailUNION.InvoDate, DetailUNION.Transaction, DetailUNION.InvoNo, DetailUNION.[No], DetailUNION.CodeProduct, DetailUNION.Info, DetailUNION.Remark, DetailUNION.NameSC;"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(CreateConnection())
            Return _conn.Query(Of DTOStockcard)(sql).ToList()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
Public Class DTOStockcard
    Public Property InvoNo() As String
    Public Property InvoDate() As Date
    Public Property Transaction() As String
    Public Property No() As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Info() As String
    Public Property Remark() As String
    Public Property NameSC() As String
    Public Property [IN] As Integer
    Public Property OUT As Integer
    Public Property BALANCE As Integer
End Class
```

Results from the above code

| Invono | Invodate | Transaction | No | Codeproduct | Info | Remark | NameSC | IN | OUT | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 18-Oct-23 | Purchase | 1 | A | WHITE | REPEAT AGAIN | TEST1 | 50 |  | 0 |
| 1000 | 18-Oct-23 | Sales | 1 | A | WHITE |  | TEST10 |  | 25 | 0 |
| 1001 | 19-Oct-23 | Purchase | 2 | A | BROWN |  | TEST2 | 25 |  | 0 |
| 1001 | 19-Oct-23 | Sales | 2 | A | WHITE |  | TEST20 |  | 15 | 0 |
| 1002 | 20-Oct-23 | Sales | 1 | A | BROWN |  | TEST30 |  | 25 | 0 |

Desired Result

| Invono | Invodate | Transaction | No | Codeproduct | Info | Remark | NameSC | IN | OUT | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 18-Oct-23 | Purchase | 1 | A | WHITE | REPEAT AGAIN | TEST1 | 50 |  | 50 |
| 1000 | 18-Oct-23 | Sales | 1 | A | WHITE |  | TEST10 |  | 25 | 25 |
| 1001 | 19-Oct-23 | Purchase | 2 | A | BROWN |  | TEST2 | 25 |  | 50 |
| 1001 | 19-Oct-23 | Sales | 2 | A | WHITE |  | TEST20 |  | 15 | 35 |
| 1002 | 20-Oct-23 | Sales | 1 | A | BROWN |  | TEST30 |  | 25 | 10 |

Comment: Huh, I didn't know what Dapper was until now. Probably because the built-in controls in Visual Studio are amazingly simple to use.

Comment: How should the `Balance` be calculated? _Sum_? _Different_? _Other Math_? Make the `Balance` property in your model `ReadOnly` and do the math in the getter and return the result. If the model does not include a required db field to do the math that you don't want to display it in the grid, add it and decorate the property with the `<Browsable(False)>` attribute.

Comment: @dr.null, OP wants a running sum. Related quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77331025/how-to-create-a-sql-item-history-stockcard-in-the-ms-access-database-in-vb-net/77334256?noredirect=1#comment136355625_77334256

Comment: @dr.null , Sorry I was late in your response. `How should the Balance be calculated? Sum? Different? Other Math?` 
so the calculation is like this `sum(IN-OUT)+BALANCE (PREVIOUS BALANCE)`  `Make the Balance property in your model ReadOnly and do the math in the getter and return the result. If the model does not include a required db field to do the math that you don't want to display it in the grid, add it and decorate the property with the <Browsable(False)> attribute.` This means I just change the property in the class then it will produce a balance column please guide me

Comment: @dr.null , `OP wants a running sum. Related quesiton stackoverflow.com/questions/77331025/…` yes you are right it is a related question but it was a post only with sql in ms access but for the balance column it still doesn't work so that's why I made a new post in a different way

Comment: *it's not right yet* -- Please describe (in the question text) what that means. Inferring it from desired output is ambiguous.

Comment: @GertArnold , `it's not right yet ` Indeed, the code I posted is not correct. `Inferring it from desired output is ambiguous`what do you mean is there something wrong with the desired result please guide me

Comment: I mean, *describe* what isn't right, don't let people guess it from a brief desired result.

Comment: So, [problem solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77334256/14171304). Very well.

Comment: @dr.null , sorry I'm late to reply. to post the problem is solved but it uses 2 sql in access queries to resolve the balance column. So I just kept using one query and for the balance column I wanted to do it with vb.net so I made this post. As you said, is your suggestion just a modification in the class or in the model, just making the balance column

Comment: @dr.null , 
If you don't mind I would like to make a new post with your suggestions so I hope you can help me, so what would be an appropriate title for the post?

Comment: Sure, feel free to do so but why? You already have two approaches to get that balance.  According to the two answers, my suggestion is based on an incorrect assumption. Having a model that includes the _current balance_, _in_, and _out_. values so you can get the running balance very easy. Besides, I don't know why your tables have duplicate fields. I recommend some reading about the _relational databases_.

Comment: @dr.null , because your suggestion is to change the balance only in that model class and also I think your suggestion is very simple. I'm very curious about your suggestions. If you don't mind, I want to make a new post especially for you`I don't know why your tables have duplicate fields. I recommend some reading about the relational databases.` You mean in `Invono` because this is only sample data but the actual data is for each transaction has different numbering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use a complex query when we can shape data from original tables.

**Classes:**

```
Public Class Invoice
    Property Invono() As Integer
    Property Invodate() As Date
    Property Transaction() As String
    Property Remark() As String
    Property NameSC() As String
End Class
    
Public Class Detail
    Public Property InvoNo() As String
    Public Property No() As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Info() As String
    Public Property Qty() As Integer
End Class
    
Public Class StockCard
    Public Property InvoNo As String
    Public Property InvoDate As Date
    Public Property Transaction As String
    Public Property No As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct As String
    Public Property Info As String
    Public Property Remark As String
    Public Property NameSC As String
    Public Property [IN] As Integer
    Public Property [OUT] As Integer
    Public Property BALANCE As Integer
End Class
```

**Declatations of data:**

```
Private Purchase, Sale As New List(Of Invoice)
Private PurchaseDetails, SaleDetails As New List(Of Detail)
```

**Loading Data using Dapper:**

```
Using Connection = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Cons)
    Purchase = Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM Purchase")
    PurchaseDetails = Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM PurchaseDetails")
    Sale = Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM Sale")
    SaleDetails = Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM SaleDetails")
End Using
```

**Creating StockCard (for CodeProduct=A):**

```
Dim ps = From p In Purchase
         From pd In PurchaseDetails
         Where pd.InvoNo = p.Invono And pd.CodeProduct = "A"
         Select
             Invono = p.Invono,
             Invodate = p.Invodate,
             p.Transaction,
             pd.No,
             pd.CodeProduct,
             pd.Info,
             p.Remark,
             p.NameSC,
             [IN] = pd.Qty,
             [OUT] = 0,
             BALANCE = pd.Qty
         Order By Invono, Invodate


Dim ss = From s In Sale
         From sd In SaleDetails
         Where sd.InvoNo = s.Invono And sd.CodeProduct = "A"
         Select
             Invono = s.Invono,
             Invodate = s.Invodate,
             s.Transaction,
             sd.No,
             sd.CodeProduct,
             sd.Info,
             s.Remark,
             s.NameSC,
             [IN] = 0,
             [OUT] =
             sd.Qty,
             BALANCE = -sd.Qty
         Order By Invono, Invodate

Dim Card_temp = ps.Union(ss).OrderBy(Function(w) w.Invono).ThenBy(Function(w) w.Invodate)

Dim Card As New List(Of Stockcard)

Dim RunningBalance As Integer = 0

For Each ct In Card_temp
    Dim sc As New StockCard
    With sc
        .InvoNo = ct.Invono
        .InvoDate = ct.Invodate
        .Transaction = ct.Transaction
        .No = ct.No
        .CodeProduct = ct.CodeProduct
        .Info = ct.Info
        .Remark = ct.Remark
        .NameSC = ct.NameSC
        .IN = ct.IN
        .OUT = ct.OUT
        .BALANCE = RunningBalance + ct.BALANCE
        RunningBalance = .BALANCE
    End With
    Card.Add(sc)
Next

DGV_Result.DataSource = Card
```

[image]

**To clear zero values:**

1- Change data type of [IN] and [OUT] in StockCard from integer to string

```
Public Property [IN] As String
Public Property [OUT] As String
```

2- Edit the select statements

```
    Dim ps = ...
    ...
    [IN] = CStr(pd.Qty),
    [OUT] = String.Empty,
    ...

   Dim ss ...
   ...
   [IN] = String.Empty,
   [OUT] = CStr(sd.Qty),
   ...
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I was late in your response. thank you for your answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry I was late marking your answer

Comment: ,hello sir, Sorry to interrupt your time, I have the latest still related to your answer in this post. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77889832/how-to-use-linq-with-union-multi-table-orderby-item-without-duplicate-with-dappe) I hope you can help me.