# how to use linq with union multi table orderby item without duplicate with dapper in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, dapper

I'm trying to use linq with union multi table orderby item without  duplicate with dapper in VB.NET.

But the result is not being duplicate is there something wrong with my code. Please Guide Me.

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Purchase, RetSales, RetPurchase, Sales As New List(Of Invoice)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadData()
    End Sub

    Private Laststock23, PurchaseDetails, RetSalesDetails, RetPurchaseDetails, SalesDetails As New List(Of Detail)
    Private Function CreateConnection() As String
        Return ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TRIAL.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    End Function
    Private Sub LoadData()
        Using Connection = New OleDbConnection(CreateConnection())
            Laststock23 = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM Laststock23"), List(Of Detail))
            Purchase = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM PURCHASE"), List(Of Invoice))
            PurchaseDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM PURCHASEDETAILS"), List(Of Detail))
            RetPurchase = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM RETPURCHASE"), List(Of Invoice))
            RetPurchaseDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM RETPURCHASEDETAILS"), List(Of Detail))
            Sales = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM SALES"), List(Of Invoice))
            SalesDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM SALESDETAILS"), List(Of Detail))
            RetSales = CType(Connection.Query(Of Invoice)("SELECT * FROM RETSALES"), List(Of Invoice))
            RetSalesDetails = CType(Connection.Query(Of Detail)("SELECT * FROM RETSALESDETAILS"), List(Of Detail))
        End Using
        Dim ls = From lsd In Laststock23
                 Select
         lsd.ITEM,
         LSQ = lsd.QTY,
         PIQ = 0,
         SIQ = 0,
         RPQ = 0,
         RSQ = 0,
        BLC = lsd.QTY
                 Order By ITEM


        Dim ps = From p In Purchase
                 From pd In PurchaseDetails
                 Select
         pd.ITEM,
         LSQ = 0,
         PIQ = pd.QTY,
         SIQ = 0,
         RPQ = 0,
         RSQ = 0,
        BLC = pd.QTY
                 Order By ITEM

        Dim ss = From s In Sales
                 From sd In SalesDetails
                 Select
         sd.ITEM,
          LSQ = 0,
          PIQ = 0,
          SIQ = sd.QTY,
          RPQ = 0,
          RSQ = 0,
             BLC = -sd.QTY
                 Order By ITEM
                 Order By ITEM
        Dim rss = From rs In RetSales
                  From rsd In RetSalesDetails
                  Select
         rsd.ITEM,
          LSQ = 0,
          PIQ = 0,
         SIQ = 0,
         RPQ = 0,
         RSQ = rsd.QTY,
             BLC = rsd.QTY
                  Order By ITEM
        Dim rps = From rp In RetPurchase
                  From rpd In RetPurchaseDetails
                  Select
         rpd.ITEM,
         LSQ = 0,
         PIQ = 0,
         SIQ = 0,
         RPQ = rpd.QTY,
         RSQ = 0,
          BLC = -rpd.QTY


        Dim Card_temp = ls.Union(ps).Union(ss).Union(rps).Union(rss).OrderBy(Function(w) w.ITEM)
        Dim Card As New List(Of ItemCards)
        Dim RunningBalance As Integer = 0
        For Each ct In Card_temp
            Dim sc As New itemCards
            With sc
                .ITEM = ct.ITEM
                .LSQ = ct.LSQ
                .PIQ = ct.PIQ
                .SIQ = ct.SIQ
                .RPQ = ct.RPQ
                .RSQ = ct.RSQ
                .BLC = RunningBalance + ct.BLC
                RunningBalance = .BLC
            End With
            Card.Add(sc)
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Card
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Invoice
    Property INVONO() As String
    Property DATEINVO() As Date
    Property CUSTCODE() As String
End Class

Public Class Detail
    Public Property INVONO() As String
    Public Property NOD() As Integer
    Public Property ITEM() As String
    Public Property QTY() As Integer

End Class
Public Class ItemCards
    Public Property ITEM() As String
    Public Property LSQ As Integer
    Public Property PIQ As Integer
    Public Property SIQ As Integer
    Public Property RSQ As Integer
    Public Property RPQ As Integer
    Public Property BLC As Integer
End Class
```

Result from code in datagridview

[image: Result from code in datagridview]

SAMPLE DATA

Table `LASTSTOCK23`

| ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| TEST 1000 | 5 |
| TEST 2000 | 10 |
| TEST 9000 | 55 |

Table `PURCHASE`

| INVONO | DATEINVO | CUSTCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PI1000 | 25-Jan-23 | 001 |
| PI1001 | 29-Jan-23 | 002 |

Table `PURCHASEDETAILS`

| INVONO | NOD | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PI1000 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 10 |
| PI1000 | 2 | TEST 2000 | 20 |
| PI1001 | 1 | TEST 3000 | 15 |

Table `SALES`

| INVONO | DATEINVO | CUSTCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SI1000 | 25-Jan-23 | 001 |
| SI1001 | 29-Jan-24 | 002 |

Table `SALESDETAILS`

| INVONO | NOD | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SI1000 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 10 |
| SI1000 | 2 | TEST 2000 | 20 |
| SI1001 | 1 | TEST 8000 | 35 |

Table `RETSALES`

| INVONO | DATEINVO | CUSTCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RS1000 | 25-Jan-23 | 001 |
| RS1001 | 29-Jan-23 | 002 |

Table `RETSALESDETAILS`

| INVONO | NOD | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RS1000 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 10 |
| RS1000 | 2 | TEST 2000 | 20 |
| RS1001 | 1 | TEST 5000 | 25 |

Table `RETPURCHASE`

| INVONO | DATEINVO | CUSTCODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RP1000 | 25-Jan-23 | 001 |
| RP1001 | 29-Jan-23 | 002 |

Table `RETPURCHASEDETAILS`

| INVONO | NOD | ITEM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RP1000 | 1 | TEST 1000 | 10 |
| RP1000 | 2 | TEST 2000 | 20 |
| RP1000 | 1 | TEST 4000 | 7 |

Desired Result

| ITEM | LSQ | PIQ | SIQ | RSQ | RPQ | BLC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 1000 | 5 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 5 |
| TEST 2000 | 10 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 10 |
| TEST 3000 |  | 15 |  |  |  | 15 |
| TEST 4000 |  |  |  |  | 7 | -7 |
| TEST 5000 |  |  |  | 25 |  | 25 |
| TEST 8000 |  |  | 35 |  |  | -35 |
| TEST 9000 | 55 |  |  |  |  | 55 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

You can use a simple query like this:

```
SELECT 
    ITEM, 
    SUM(LS) AS LSQ, 
    SUM(PI) AS PIQ, 
    SUM(SI) AS SIQ, 
    SUM(RS) AS RSQ, 
    SUM(RP) AS RPQ, 
    SUM(B)  AS BLC
FROM (
    SELECT ITEM, QTY AS LS,   0 AS PI,   0 AS SI,   0 AS RS,   0 AS RP,  QTY AS B FROM LastStock23
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ITEM,   0 AS LS, QTY AS PI,   0 AS SI,   0 AS RS,   0 AS RP,  QTY AS B FROM PurchaseDetails
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ITEM,   0 AS LS,   0 AS PI,   0 AS SI,   0 AS RS, QTY AS RP, -QTY AS B FROM RetPurchaseDetails
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ITEM,   0 AS LS,   0 AS PI, QTY AS SI,   0 AS RS,   0 AS RP, -QTY AS B FROM SalesDetails
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ITEM,   0 AS LS,   0 AS PI,   0 AS SI, QTY AS RS,   0 AS RP,  QTY AS B FROM RetSalesDetails
    )  AS CARDEX
GROUP BY ITEM
ORDER BY ITEM
```

Its better if you keep all transaction in a single table and add a field for transaction type (purchase, detail, return-purchase, return-detail)

**Update 2: Using LINQ**

The LINQ codes have some unnecessary parts which should be removed.

First of all, the `Purchase`, `RetPurchase`, `Sales`, and `RetSales` tables are not needed in this case - only the details are needed.

Second, nested selects like `Dim ps = From p In Purchase From pd In PurchaseDetails` have negative impact on performance because of unneeded loops. Also any ordering before grouping is unnecessary and should be removed.

Third, instead of loading the raw tables and shaping the data as cards using LINQ in multiple steps, it is better to load primary cards with appropriate simple queries and then use a single simple LINQ code.

```
Public Class ItemCards
    Public Property ITEM() As String
    Public Property LSQ() As Integer
    Public Property PIQ() As Integer
    Public Property SIQ() As Integer
    Public Property RSQ() As Integer
    Public Property RPQ() As Integer
    Public Property BLC() As Integer
End Class

Private Laststock23, PurchaseDetails, RetSalesDetails, RetPurchaseDetails, SalesDetails As New List(Of ItemCards)

Const Qry_LS = "SELECT ITEM, QTY AS LSQ,   0 AS PIQ,   0 AS SIQ,   0 AS RSQ,   0 AS RPQ,  QTY AS BLC FROM LastStock23"
Const Qry_PI = "SELECT ITEM,   0 AS LSQ, QTY AS PIQ,   0 AS SIQ,   0 AS RSQ,   0 AS RPQ,  QTY AS BLC FROM PurchaseDetails"
Const Qry_RP = "SELECT ITEM,   0 AS LSQ,   0 AS PIQ,   0 AS SIQ,   0 AS RSQ, QTY AS RPQ, -QTY AS BLC FROM RetPurchaseDetails"
Const Qry_SI = "SELECT ITEM,   0 AS LSQ,   0 AS PIQ, QTY AS SIQ,   0 AS RSQ,   0 AS RPQ, -QTY AS BLC FROM SalesDetails"
Const Qry_RS = "SELECT ITEM,   0 AS LSQ,   0 AS PIQ,   0 AS SIQ, QTY AS RSQ,   0 AS RPQ,  QTY AS BLC FROM RetSalesDetails"

Using Connection = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Cons)
    With Connection
        Laststock23 = .Query(Of ItemCards)(Qry_LS)
        PurchaseDetails = .Query(Of ItemCards)(Qry_PI)
        RetPurchaseDetails = .Query(Of ItemCards)(Qry_RP)
        SalesDetails = .Query(Of ItemCards)(Qry_SI)
        RetSalesDetails = .Query(Of ItemCards)(Qry_RS)
    End With
End Using

Dim Cardex =
    From card In Laststock23.Union(PurchaseDetails).Union(RetPurchaseDetails).Union(SalesDetails).Union(RetSalesDetails)
    Group card By card.ITEM Into Group
    Let LSQ = (From x In Group Select x.LSQ).Sum
    Let PIQ = (From x In Group Select x.PIQ).Sum
    Let SIQ = (From x In Group Select x.SIQ).Sum
    Let RPQ = (From x In Group Select x.RPQ).Sum
    Let RSQ = (From x In Group Select x.RSQ).Sum
    Let BLC = (From x In Group Select x.BLC).Sum
    Select ITEM, LSQ, PIQ, SIQ, RPQ, RSQ, BLC
    Order By ITEM

DGV_Cardex.DataSource = Cardex.ToList
```

[image: the output]

Comment: thank you for your answer . for tables `LASTSTOCK23` 
This is the final stock table in 2023 so the current purchase table in 2024 is `PURCHASEDETAILS` 
so there must be purchases for new items that are not in the table `LASTSTOCK23` . Example adding items `TEST 3000` in table `PURCHASEDETAILS` 
If I use the query above then the new item will not appear. Please Guide me

Comment: With current sample data it is not possible to check if the code/query works. Please edit the tables data (and desired output) with more records (non-repetitive values and non-equal number of records of course).

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I have updated the post with sample data and desired results. is it better to use Linq? or you can provide 2 options: simple SQL query and Linq

Comment: See the updated answer. I think the task is simple enough to be done in a query.

Comment: Your 2 answer options really helped me and were perfect.

Comment: hello sir , I have a new post that is still related to your answer. Maybe you can help me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905086/how-to-use-sql-linq-with-union-multi-table-orderby-groupby-item-without-duplic)

Comment: Hello sir, 
Does this post link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905086/how-to-use-sql-linq-with-union-multi-table-orderby-groupby-item-without-duplic) have any recommendations for solutions from you?